# Odd behaviour of values()

Tags: gremlin

In Gremlin console, I see the following:

1) Setup

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
```

2) Insert

```
g.addV('mylabel').property(id, 1).property('name', 'myname').next()
```

3) This works fine:

```
g.V(1).values('name')
==>myname // as expected
```

3) This instead gives unexpected result

```
g.V().sideEffect{println it.get().values('name')}
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.iterator.IteratorUtils$3@12a14b74 // expected: "myname"
```

Shouldn't `it.get()` be the vertex and `values('name')` be `"myname"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking strictly to the API and usage of `Vertex.values()` in a `sideEffect()` step, you're getting precisely what you asked for because `values()` returns an `Iterator` - see [javadocs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Element.html#values-java.lang.String...-). You need to instead do:

```
g.V().sideEffect{println it.get().values('name').next()}
```

or better (assuming "name" isn't a multi-property):

```
g.V().sideEffect{println it.get().value('name')}
```

or better still, avoid the closure/`sideEffect()` and just do:

```
g.V().values('name')
```